# Does the Illumination sensor on iPhone and iPad adjusts RGB values automatically?

Tags: ios, image-processing, opengl-es, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

The iPhone and iPad have different AvCaptureDevice methods to lock or put on Auto: white balance and exposure settings.

I am trying to understand the mechanism of the "Backside illumination sensor" on the back camera and now the front camera and whether it adjusts the white balance and exposure setting and if that is the case, would locking the WB and exposure mode would be interfering with the "Backside illumination sensor" job.

Or, is the "Backside illumination sensor" simply and only boosting the RGB values of the pixels in low light?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're a little confused about what the term "backside illuminated sensor" means here. This is a just a type of CMOS sensor used in the new iPhones (and other mobile phones). It claims to have better low-light performance than older CMOS imagers, but it is just what captures the photos and videos, not a separate sensor for detecting light levels. There is a light sensor on the front face of the device, but that's just for adjusting the brightness of the screen in response to lighting conditions.

In my experience, all automatic exposure and gain correction done by the iPhone is based on the average luminance of the scene captured by the camera. When I've done whole-image luminance averaging, I've found that the iPhone camera almost always maintains an average luminance of around 50%. This seems to indicate that it uses the image captured by the sensor to determine exposure and gain settings for the camera (and probably white balance leveling, too).

Comment: Thanks. So the "backside illuminated" part is just a feature added to the existing sensor and locking WB and exposure would stop the camera from adjusting to the sensor data trying to provide an image with 50% average luminance. This pegs the questions: Many of the code (openGL and not) trying to detect colors in captured output frames tries as a first step to remove luminance component to be able to compare pixels. Why is that necessary if luminance is always the same (50%)?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 - Because luminance varies significantly across a scene. The average luminance of a scene averages everything seen by the camera, but your region of interest might only be 10-20% of that frame. Luminance can even vary across an object.

Comment: I see. you said "Whole-image luminance averaging". Thanks

Comment: And so the reason that it is preferable to use algorithms that compares pixels RGB after removing luminance versus trying to lock WB and exposure and compare frame pixels is because there are other variables that could impact Luminance beyond WB and exposure (and that cannot be locked)?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 - Yes, as I said, the luminance of objects within a individual scene can vary significantly, even across the object itself. Take a colored ball and observe how the fringes are darker or lighter than the center. Move that ball across the camera's field of view, change its distance from the camera, and you'll see variances in the overall luminance of that uniformly-colored ball.